# Why is my game bot endlessly checking instead of changing "channels"?

Tags: python

This bot is something I originally found online and have been editing and changing/adding things to learn some things about coding in the process. There are things in the game called "runes" and essentially it's a bot check where the bot has to perform arrow keys to "ensure it's not a bot". If the bot messes up the bot check, it can reset and try again. As you can see from this segment of code - the one I'm working on and having issues with.

Also, changing "channels" is essentially changing "worlds" in game. So by changing channels you essentially reset the bot check.

```
                #Check for rune
            now = time.time()
            if settings.rent_frenzy == False and settings.story_mode == False:
                if not config.bot.rune_active:
                    filtered = utils.filter_color(minimap, RUNE_RANGES)
                    matches = utils.multi_match(filtered, RUNE_TEMPLATE, threshold=0.9)
                    rune_start_time = now
                    if matches and config.routine.sequence:
                        abs_rune_pos = (matches[0][0], matches[0][1])
                        config.bot.rune_pos = utils.convert_to_relative(abs_rune_pos, minimap)
                        print('rune pos : ',config.bot.rune_pos)
                        distances = list(map(distance_to_rune, config.routine.sequence))
                        index = np.argmin(distances)
                        config.bot.rune_closest_pos = config.routine[index].location
                        print('rune_closest_pos : ',config.bot.rune_closest_pos)
                        config.bot.rune_active = True
                        rune_check_count = 0
                elif now - rune_start_time > self.rune_alert_delay and now - config.latest_solved_rune >= (60 * int(settings.rune_cd_min) + self.rune_alert_delay):     # Alert if rune hasn't been solved
                    config.bot.rune_active = False
                    self._send_msg_to_line_notify("Puzzle solving took too long")
                    if settings.auto_change_channel:
                        config.should_change_channel = True
                    else:
                        pass
                elif config.bot.solve_rune_fail_count >= 3 and not settings.auto_change_channel:
                    self._send_msg_to_line_notify("Multiple failed puzzle solving attempts")
```

I believe this command,  `config.should_change_channel = True`,  should be what forces my character to change channels, but it doesn't. Also, all of the `self._send_msg_to_line_notify("Puzzle solving took too long")`
messages never end up appearing in my CMD - so I'm unsure if those lines are even being run. Below are the links to the notifier doc where all of this code is and also attached the config file it references.
If needed, I also added the components.py which I believe has the command it runs to change channels.

### [notifier.py](https://pastebin.com/WuLciKDJ)
[config.py](https://pastebin.com/MfRH8bFJ)

Command in [components.py](https://pastebin.com/UgJBrFAp)